# How do I find standard deviation in this problem?

Tags: standard-deviation

In the ordered line : 
X:   4,    5,   9,    10,  11,  13,  16
P(X) 0.12, 0.1, 0.11,0.11,0.14,0.34,0,08
 what is standard deviation?
the mean is 10.31
Can you guys help me to find the standard deviation?

Comment: I wanted to you the table to denote:

Comment: X  4 5 9 10 11  13  16
P(X) 0.12 0.1 0.11 0.11 0.14 0.34 0.08

Comment: You have asked : "what is the standard deviation" ; I have answered you in  mathematical terms. The way to arrange it into a table is another thing : I would advise you to take a look at your lecture notes for this. What is your level of study ? 5-7 grade in high school ?

Comment: I knew the formula to find out the standard deviation but I need the answer of standard deviation, not a formula, we all knew how to find the standard deviation. But in this situation, I cannot use the normal formula to solve. Ok, for example, the probability of 4 is 0.12; the probability of 5 is 0.10,... but we do not know how many numbers are there? when I try in a hard way by using my calculator I guess n = 100. well, haha, I must put 100 number into my caculator? That's a stupid way. So, that I mean

Comment: I beg your pardon, but your question wasn't clear enough.  Make a first line with the $X_k$s. Make a second line with the frequencies $p_k$. Make a third line with the squares $(X_k)^2$. Make a fourth line with the $p_k(X_k)^2$. Summing this fourth line and dividing it by $n-1$ will give you $E(X^2)$. Now it remains  to subtract $E(X)^2=m^2$ to obtain the variance, then take its square root.

Comment: never mind. ok, everything is ok. I understood the way to get the answer yesterday. Thank you for your help. I appreciate that.  You are smart!  totally,  Variance = sigma p(x) * [ rx - E(rx)] ^2 and then, take it square root, we have standard deviation.

Comment: This is not the most efficient formula : consider the alternative formula which under its theoretical form is $V(X)=E(X^2)-E(X)^2$.